# Having more than one if statements in one IBAction in the .m file isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am making an iPhone app that will generate something based on quiz answers. I want the button for the answer to change the question text and sometimes the button label text.

Background Info:

- 'a' is a button
- 'questionNumber' is the question number (duh) and it is why the button will change the texts differently each time it is pressed.

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(IBAction) a 
{
    questionNumber == 0;

    if(questionNumber == 0) {

        question.text = @"How Much Do You Use Suppressed Weapons?";
    }

    questionNumber == 1;

    if(questionNumber == 1) {

        question.text = @"Do You Like Sleight of Hand?";

        answerA.text = @"Yes";
        answerB.text = @"No";
        [answerC setHidden:YES];
        [answerD setHidden:YES];
        [answerButton3 setHidden:YES];
        [answerButton4 setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

and this repeats for the other buttons (b,c, and d). I thought it should work, but it doesn't do the "do you like sleight of hand" question. It just stays at the how much do you use suppressed weapons question. Please Help! I really want to get into xcoding for the iphone.
BTW, I am not sure that the tags for this question are correct.

Related Question: [How can I have an IBAction that has more than two 'if' statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940983/how-can-i-have-an-ibaction-that-has-more-than-two-if-statements)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using a `switch` statement with `breaks`.

```
switch (questionNumber)
{
    case 0:
    {
        question.text = @"How Much Do You Use Suppressed Weapons?";
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
           question.text = @"Do You Like Sleight of Hand?";

           answerA.text = @"Yes";
           answerB.text = @"No";
           [answerC setHidden:YES];
           [answerD setHidden:YES];
           [answerButton3 setHidden:YES];
           [answerButton4 setHidden:YES];
    }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that. But I don't understand what those terms mean. Could you help me?

Comment: Similar to an if statement, only specific to integers, where "questionNumber" has to be an integer. The break assures that the calls stop for that case and dont proceed.

Comment: Okay, that makes mores sense. I will try the code you gave me.

Comment: Also, if you are going to have questions like this, you should store them in a plist or sqlite db, along with the acceptable answers, this will clean your IBAction code up alot. Thats just how I would write a "questions" app.

Comment: I tried it, and it will go to the how much do you use suppressed weapons question, but after that, it wont go any further. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure how you are navigating through your questions. Maybe you can include more code in your question.

Comment: How would I do that? The breakdown goes like this:

Comment: sorry, accidentally pressed enter                                        You press start at the main menu, then it will display a question, 4 uibuttons, and a label next to each button.

Comment: after you press a button, it should display the next question and change the button label text if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning to `questionNumber`. You're comparing.

```
questionNumber == 1;
```

That's a noop. It tests if `questionNumber` is 1, and then throws away the result. You want

```
questionNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that just now, but now it is skipping the how much do you use suppressed weapons question.